# Locate beginning or the first line (of file) in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to add a string on the beginning of multiple files. How could i match the file beginning?

To locate a *line* beginning isn't a problem - just search for something like `\r\n`, but the beginning of the *first line*...

Comment: You can use `^` to mark the beginning of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex, we use the caret character to match the beginning of a string / line.

Then in notepad++, use the replace in regex mode and perform one single replace instead of Replace All to only change the first line of the file.

To confine the search to a single line and therefore be able to do a Replace in All Files, include the newline characters in the exception list, e.g. [^\r\n]. The meaning of the caret character in this usage is "All except" (not to confuse with the first caret meaning beginning of string).

The regex to search would be:

```
^([^\r\n]*)
```

The regex to replace would be:

```
YOUR STRING$1
```